# add external folder to OSGI bundle classpath

Tags: localization, classpath, osgi, glassfish-3

I need to add L10N support in OSGI bundle. I would like to put all the resource properties in conf/resource folder outside a bundle (to make them visible from any bundle).

Is there an option to add a folder to the classpath of OSGI bundle?

**Upd:**
I saw that OSGI propose to add resource bundles inside fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

1. Put the l10n resources in their own bundle, and use the usual OSGi dependency mechanism to access them from other bundles. After all, this is how OSGi was meant to be used.
2. Put the l10n resources in their own directory, and have the bundles read them as files. This means the l10n resources cannot be deployed as a bundle, and that you may run into permission issues related to I/O.
3. If only one bundle needs l10n resources, the resources can indeed be bundled as fragments. Fragments are bundles that are attached to a host bundle. You could have one fragment bundle per language/locale, and all of them would have the using bundle as host.
4. If you only need to localize the OSGi headers, it's very easy; I doubt this is what you need though.

Solution 1 is definitely the way to go and stay in the OSGi spirit. Solution 2 is awful if you ask me. Solution 3 is nice if each bundle can be localized independently.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response!
I go for solution 3, because I have several clients that need to add L10N resources, so they will be in separate modules. I will put them in separate fragments, every fragment contains 1 l10n resource with all the supported locales.